# WriteFile() Truncating String

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

```
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;


if (lastTitle != buffer) {
    //write new title;
    WriteFile(file, "\n\nWindow: ", sizeof("\n\nWindow: "), NULL, NULL);
    WriteFile(file, buffer.c_str(), sizeof(buffer), NULL, NULL);
    WriteFile(file, "\n", sizeof("\n"), NULL, NULL);
    std::cout << GetLastError(); //this is showing 0, which means no error
```

Cout is outputting:

C:\Users\riseo\Desktop\C++\my_proj\Debug\my_proj.exe

The file that is being written to is showing:

Window:  C:\Users\riseo\Desktop\C++\m

I'm not quite sure why this is being truncated, it should be the same as what cout is printing.  Im sorry this post doesn't show much research, but I've been getting burned by various string-format related gotchas all day and I have no clue what is happening here.  All I can think of is maybe something with c_str() is going wrong.

Comment: "*I've been getting burned by various string-format related gotchas all day  and I have no clue what is happening here*" - then you clearly do not understand how strings are represented in memory, and how formatting functions/operators work. You need to brush up on your C/C++ basics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seriously misusing `sizeof()`.  `WriteFile()` operates on bytes, but you are passing it character data.  String literals contain a null terminator that `sizeof()` would include, which you don't want in this case.  And `std::string()` contains a pointer to the character data, so `sizeof(std::string)` does not account for the true character length.

You need to do this instead:

```
//write new title;
WriteFile(file, "\n\nWindow: ", strlen("\n\nWindow: "), NULL, NULL);
WriteFile(file, buffer.c_str(), buffer.length(), NULL, NULL);
WriteFile(file, "\n", strlen("\n"), NULL, NULL);
```

A wrapper function would be better:

```
bool WriteStringToFile(HANDLE hFile, const std::string &str)
{
    return WriteFile(hFile, str.c_str(), str.length(), NULL, NULL);
}

...

//write new title;
WriteStringToFile(file, "\n\nWindow: ");
WriteStringToFile(file, buffer);
WriteStringToFile(file, "\n");
```

A `std::ofstream` would be even better:

```
std::ofstream ofs("myfile.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
...
ofs << "\n\nWindow: " << buffer << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my problem and giving such elegant solutions.  +1

Comment: The second call can be without that .c_str(), i.e. `WriteStringToFile(file, buffer);`, currently you do an unnecessary conversion std::string -> const char* -> std::string.